# Convergence of infinite series involving factorials

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, factorial

How can I determine the convergence/divergence of $\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac {1}{\ln\left({k!}\right)}$?

Comment: Do you know Stirling's formula?

Comment: @carmichael561 No. Also, the only tests for convergence that I know are the Integral Test, Comparison Test, and Limit Comparison Test.

Answer (score 9):

**Hint.** $\ln(k!) \leq k \ln k.{}{}$

Comment: Thank you. Then I can simply use the Comparison Test to prove that the series diverges. However, how can I prove that ln(k!)≤k*lnk?

Comment: I can give you the answer, but you've only had five minutes to think about it. Are you sure you want to hear it?

Comment: No it's fine. I already figured it out. I wrote ln(k!)<=k*lnk. Then used log properties to write ln(k!)<=ln(k^k). After that I cancelled the logs to get k!<=k^k which is obviously true.

Comment: Okay, but your chain of implications should start with $k! \leq k^k$ and go in the other direction.